# python errno 24 on cgi script using subprocess

Tags: python, cgi, subprocess

I have a python cgi script that runs an application via subprocess over and over again (several thousand times).  I keep getting the same error...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/linuser/Webpages/cgi/SnpEdit.py", line 413, in <module>
    webpage()
  File "/home/linuser/Webpages/cgi/SnpEdit.py", line 406, in main
    displayOmpResult(form['odfFile'].value)
  File "/home/linuser/Webpages/cgi/SnpEdit.py", line 342, in displayContainerDiv
    makeSection(position,sAoiInput)
  File "/home/linuser/Webpages/cgi/SnpEdit.py", line 360, in displayData
    displayTable(i,j,lAmpAndVars,dOligoSet[key],position)
  File "/home/linuser/Webpages/cgi/SnpEdit.py", line 247, in displayTable
    p = subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/pDat',sInputFileLoc,sOutputFileLoc],stdout=fh, stderr=fh)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 633, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1039, in _execute_child
    errpipe_read, errpipe_write = os.pipe()
OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files
```

The function causing it is below.

```
def displayTable(sData):

    # convert the data to the proper format
    sFormattedData = convertToFormat(sData)

    # write the formatted data to file
    sInputFile = tempfile.mkstemp(prefix='In_')[1]
    fOpen = open(sInputFile,'w')
    fOpen.write(sFormattedData)
    fOpen.close()

    sOutputFileLoc = sInputFile.replace('In_','Out_')

    # run app, requires two files; an input and an output
    # temp file to holds stdout stderr of subprocess
    fh = tempfile.TemporaryFile(mode='w',dir=tempfile.gettempdir())
    p = subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/pDat',sInputFileLoc,sOutputFileLoc],stdout=fh, stderr=fh)
    p.communicate()
    fh.close()

    # open output file and print parsed data into a list of dictionaries
    sOutput = open(sOutputFileLoc).read()
    lOutputData = parseOutput(sOutput)

    displayTableHeader(lOutputData)
    displaySimpleTable(lOutputData)
```

As far as I can tell, I'm closing the files properly.  When I run...

```
import resource
print resource.getrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_NOFILE)
```

I get...

```
(1024, 1024)
```

Do I have to increase this value?  I read that subprocess opens several file descriptors.  I tried adding "close_fds = True" and I tried using the with statement when creating my file but the result was the same.  I suspect the problem may be with the application that I'm subprocessing, pDat, but this program was made by someone else.  It requires two inputs; an input file and the location of where you want the output file written to.  I suspect it may not be closing the output file that it creates.  Aside from this, I can't see what I might be doing wrong.  Any suggestions?  Thanks.

EDIT:
I'm on ubuntu 10.04 running python 2.6.5 and apache 2.2.14

Comment: The result of `open()` is assigned to nothing. Did you miss the `fOpen=`?

Comment: Sorry, must have accidently deleted that during my edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this...

```
sInputFile = tempfile.mkstemp(prefix='In_')[1]
fOpen = open(sInputFile,'w')
fOpen.write(sFormattedData)
fOpen.close()
```

I should have done this...

```
iFileHandle,sInputFile = tempfile.mkstemp(prefix='In_')
fOpen = open(sInputFile,'w')
fOpen.write(sFormattedData)
fOpen.close()
os.close(iFileHandle)
```

The mkstemp function makes OS level handles to a file and I wasn't closing them.  The solution is described in more detail here...
http://www.logilab.org/blogentry/17873

Answer (score 0):

You want to add `close_fds=True` to the `popen` call (just in case).

Then, here:

```
# open output file and print parsed data into a list of dictionaries
    sOutput = open(sOutputFileLoc).read()
    lOutputData = parseOutput(sOutput)
```

...I might remember wrong, but unless you use the `with` syntax, I do not think that the output file descriptor has been closed.

**UPDATE**: the main problem is that *you need to know which files are open*. On Windows this would require something like Process Explorer. In Linux it's a bit simpler; you just have to invoke the CGI from command line, or be sure that there is only *one* instance of the CGI running, and fetch its pid with `ps` command.

Once you have the pid, run a `ls -la` on the content of the `/proc/<PID>/fd` directory. All open file descriptors will be there, with the name of the files they point to. Knowing that file so-and-so is opened 377 times, that goes a long way towards finding out *where* exactly that file is opened (but not closed).

Comment: He should always use the "with" syntax anyway, its good practice.

Comment: I did try this, but the result was the same.  I also tried using the with statement but got the same error.

Comment: You closed the sOutput handle, and yet you still exhaust the files? Well, maybe there's a way. Editing answer...